# Parsing CSV file which includes a header block of "comments"

Tags: csv, parsing, go, text

I'm trying to parse a CSV file hosted in a remote location, but annoyingly the file contains some readme comments atop the file, in the following format:

```
######
# some readme text,
# some more, comments
###### 
01-02-03,123,foo,http://example.com 
04-05-06,789,baz,http://another.com
```

I'm attempting to use the following code in order to extract the URLs within the data, but it throws an error saying `wrong number of fields` due to the comments at the top, presumably it's trying to parse them as CSV content.

```
type myData struct {
  URL string `json:"url"`
}

func doWork() ([]myData, error) {
  rurl := "https://example.com/some.csv"
  out := make([]myData, 0)
  
  resp, err := http.Get(rurl)
  if err != nil {
    return []myData{}, err
  }

  defer resp.Body.Close()
  reader := csv.NewReader(resp.Body)
  reader.Comma = ','
  data, err := reader.ReadAll()
  if err != nil {
    return []myData{}, err
  }

  for _, row := range data {
    out = append(out, myData{URL: row[4]})
  }

  return out, nil
}

func main() {
  data, err := doWork()
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  // do something with data
}
```

Is there a way to skip over the first N lines of the remote file, or have it ignore lines which start with a #

Comment: Thanks, could you give a suggestion on how I would implement a filter?

Comment: Lines that start with # are comments in lots of csv files I have seen.  I think it's part of the standard.

Comment: @WalterMitty: there is no csv "standard", there is the informational RFC4180 which does not mention comments at all, meaning it is up to the parsing application to determine if comments are allowed, and what the syntax is. (I forgot the go `csv.Reader` provides a way convenient configure filter lines, which @c0nt0s0 found below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, actually I just realised I can add this:

```
reader.Comment = '#' // ignores the line starting with '#'
```

Which works perfectly with my current code, but appreciate the other suggestions.

Comment: Don't hesitate to mark your own answer as accepted—it's perfectly normal as per SO rules ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I will, although SO tells me I have to wait 2 days..

Answer (score 1):

Well, the approach is simple: do not try to interpret the lines starting with '#' as part of the CSV stream; instead, consider the whole stream of data as a concatenation of two streams: the header and the actual CSV payload.

The easiest approach probably is to employ the fact `bufio.Reader` is able to read lines from its underlying stream and it itself is an `io.Reader` so you can make a `csv.Reader` to read from *it* instead of the source stream.

So, you could roll like this (not real code, untested):

```golang
import (
  "bufio"
  "encoding/csv"
  "io"
  "strings"
)

func parse(r io.Reader) ([]MyData, error) (
  br := bufio.NewReader(r)

  var line string
  for {
    s, err := br.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
      return nil, err
    }
    if len(s) == 0 || s[0] != '#' {
      line = s
      break
    }
  }

  // At this point the line variable contains the 1st line of the CSV stream.
  // Let's create a "multi reader" which reads first from that line
  // and then — from the rest of the CSV stream.
  cr := csv.NewReader(io.MultiReader(strings.NewReader(line), br))
  cr.Comma = ','
  data, err := cr.ReadAll()
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  for _, row := range data {
    out = append(out, myData{URL: row[4]})
  }

  return out, nil
}
```